# links on top of absolute image become un-clickable

Tags: html, absolute

I've tried changing the z-index for the image and hyperlink with no luck. If I remove the image(girl.png) the link works. What am I doing wrong?

```
     <table width="842" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f9a531" style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:50px; padding-right:20px;">
  <tr><td height="30" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ashleys-Hair-Design/299450416776890https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ashleys-Hair-Design/299450416776890" target="_blank"><img src="http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/facebook.gif" height="18" width="8" border="0" alt="Ashley Hair Design facebook page"></a>
  <br />
  </td></tr>
  </table>
<!-- End top bar -->



    <table  width="842"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e6e4e1" style="background-image:url(http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/bg1.gif); background-position:top; background-repeat:repeat-y; padding-top:30px;padding-left:50px; padding-right:30px;">

      <tr><td>
    <img src="http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/ashley.jpg" width="375" height="500" alt="Ashley Wright Hair Designer" align="middle">
        </td>      


      <td valign="top" align="left">
    <img src="http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/logo.png" width="290" height="131" border="0" alt="Ashley Hair Salon in Manotick"  vspace="0" />  
      <br /><br />
      <h3>
         613-715-HAIR (4247)<br />
         <a href="mailto:ashleywright63@mac.com" class="content-links">ashleywright63@mac.com</a><br />
         5562-B Manotick Main st. <br />
         Manotick, ON K4M 1B3<br />
      </h3>


      <img src="http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/hours.png" /><br />
      Tue 9:00 - 6:00<br />
      Wed - Thu 9:00 - 8:00<br />           
      Fri 9:00 - 6:00<br />
      Sat 9:00 - 4:00<br />
      Sun &amp; Mon - Closed<br /><br />
    <img src="http://ashleyshairdesign.ca/images/girl.png" alt="Ashleys Hair Salon" style="position:absolute; top:34%; left:53%;" class="transparent" />   
    <a href="http://www.schedulicity.com/Scheduling/Default.aspx?business=AHDZC3" title="Online scheduling" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.schedulicity.com/Business/Images/ScheduleNow_LG.png" alt="Schedule online now" border="0"  /></a> 
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
        <br /><br />
      <h3 style="margin:0px;">Beauty and Personal care</h3>
      Experience in special occasion updos, contemporary styling and technical ability<br /><br /> 
    </td></tr>
      </table>
```

Website: [ashleyshairdesign.ca](http://ashleyshairdesign.ca)

Comment: Maybe you could post yout code on http://jsfiddle.net. That's easier to edit for someone! Concerning your question, maybe remove the z-index of the image!

Comment: You should remove the div that hold you link! There's no need to out the link in an div!

See your working code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjhW6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the div that hold you link! There's no need to out the link in an div!

```
<div style="z-index:2;">link</div>
<a href="http://www.schedulicity.com/Scheduling/Default.aspx?business=AHDZC3" title="Online scheduling" target="_blank" style="z-index:3;position:absolute;">
```

See your working code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4xeH/1/

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

**Edit:**

Updated the jsfiddle! Like I noticed, z-index only works if on **positioned elements**! You didn't position the `<a href></a>` so the z-index never worked for the `<a></a>` element and that's why the image was on top of the link.

If you look at your HTML, try to put styling in a CSS file, avoid inline styling. Also do not table's for layout. Tables must be used for showing data like you would in an Excel file. Use div's instead and position them!

Comment: I removed the div but that didn't make the link clickable

Comment: Check the code on jsfiddle! It just works fine there for me! We are talking about he schedule link,  aren't we?

Comment: I have added the path to the image since the problem occurs when you can see the image. Yes, its the schedule link that doesn't work.

Comment: But did you look at the code I posted on jsfiddle? Works fine for me!

Comment: Yes, I did. The reason it works is that the image (girl.png) was not loaded. When I entered the full path to the image, the image loaded and it didn't work.

Comment: hmm, I thought I updated the jsfiddle. You can see: www.ashleyshairdesign.ca

Comment: @user3298211, changed my answer, updated your code and now it should be working! Also reed my edit!

Answer (score 1):

Malformed HTML:

```
<div style="z-index:2;>"
```

Comment: I fixed the mal-formed html but that wasn't the solution

Answer (score 0):

So, i stripped down your code to this:

```
<table width="842" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e6e4e1" >
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="left">
            <div style="z-index:2;>"
                <a href="http://www.schedulicity.com/Scheduling/Default.aspx?business=AHDZC3" title="Online scheduling" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.schedulicity.com/Business/Images/ScheduleNow_LG.png" alt="Schedule online now" border="0" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything was removed and the link still didn't work. Then i corrected an error: " to  --> moving the " inside the > and the link starts working.

Then I put all your codes back in and made that one change

```
<div style="z-index:2;">
```

The link still works.